# Progress dialog not displayed in android?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I use the progress dialog while hitting web service and wait for response from web service ,once i got the response i dismiss the progress dialog. here is the code i use for that,

```
      dialog= ProgressDialog.show(Settings.this, "","Synchronisation with  server...", false);
      request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
      envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
      androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

      request.addProperty("mtest","1");


      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
          try
          {
              System.gc();
              androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
              SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


              }
              }

              dialog.dismiss();
          }
          catch (Exception aE)
          {
              aE.printStackTrace ();;
          }
```

but the progress is not appear, if web service connected if i send the request , the application seems to be idle and does not show any progress until it got the response , i need to show some progress.

If web service is not connected the progress is displayed , but we can`t dismiss it manually.
          i need to show indication of progress while hitting web service, either as separate progress or as a part of title itself. If any one know please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your remote calls to a secondary thread with Handler or use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do the work.

Reason is, when you do ProgressDialog.Show, it scheduled the show in next update (in UI thread), which is the same thread as you are connecting web service; Hence, it never get the chance to do so since your web service is holding the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Many people face the this problem, even i also facing same problem. The best solution for this is to use the Async Task. Hear is a [sample code](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/) for that . It may help you.